# 'make' not found when I try to make a shared library file on Windows 10 in RStudio

Tags: r, fortran, shared-libraries

```
require(devtools)
assignInNamespace("version_info", 
              c(devtools:::version_info,
                list("3.5" = list(version_min = "3.3.0",
                                  version_max = "99.99.99", 
                                  path = "bin"))),
              "devtools")
find_rtools() # TRUE
system('R CMD SHLIB facto.f') ## got an error 
dyn.load('facto.so') ## haven't run yet. .so or .dll
```

Hi

With the code above and gfortran compiler, I'm trying to make a shared library file (.so or .dll) and load it to my RStudio on Windows 10.

The original code I found said that I should create a ".so" file. 
But as I'm working on Windows 10, I think I should create ".dll" file instead.

Referring to a web ([link to R-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/fortran-and-r-speed-things-up/)) I made a Fortran script named "facto.f" and tried to compile it in RStudio with the system() function above; I failed to compile with an error:

> In system(cmd) : 'make' not found

I checked my system has gfortran with "gcc -v" in cmd (version 6.3.0).

I also registered the gfortran to my environment path (C:\MinGW\bin).

Running the system() with -o flag (e.g. system('R CMD SHLIB -o fsmm.dll facto.f')
also prompted the same error.

**How can I make .so (or .dll) file in RStudio on Windows 10?**

Comment: Did you install rtools? https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ You're going to need a working copy of `make` to compile and windows doesnt come with one.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I did. But R didn't recognize it (find_rools() returned "FALSE") so I added assignInNamespace(~~), which made find_rtools() to return "TRUE"

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by reinstalling the Rtools.

After doing that, find_rtools() returned "TRUE" without running assignInNamespace(~~) in the above code.

Thank you.